# How can I get the remote client IP address using Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Is it possible to get the remote client IP adress if I need to get this informantion to log a user activity by example?

PS.: I'm using Oracle APEX 4.2 version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Oracle APEX you can get the remote client IP address using the OWA_UTIL package like the example bellow:

```
select owa_util.get_cgi_env ('REMOTE_ADDR') from dual;
```

As described in the documentation:

> The OWA_UTIL package contains utility subprograms for performing operations such as getting the value of CGI environment variables [...].

[OWA_UTIL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/w_util.htm#CHDFFJIH)